# Variant of coupon collector's problem

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

If each box of cereal contains 2 different prizes at random and there are 7 prizes total, how many boxes would you expect to open in order to collect all 7 prizes?

The standard version of this problem has 1 prize per box.  [See here.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem?wprov=sfla1)

Can this be generalized for *n* total prizes and *k* different prizes per box?

Comment: If you search the site for coupon collector you find several posts in this direction.

Comment: @RossMillikan: That was the wrong duplicate; it had random group sizes; I've replaced it by one with fixed group sizes. Since I keep searching for these various variations, I added them all to [the probability part](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29382) of the "List of Generalizations of Common Questions".

Comment: Here is an example of a similar problem with 5 prizes per box: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402850/how-many-hypothetical-packs-do-i-need-to-get-every-card-in-a-set